# if statement in dropdown menu with condition from existing values

Tags: php, if-statement

Hi what i would like to do in my dropdown is to put a condition if($formdata[0]['Phase']==1){ to show only the option values from $ahk 1x in dropdown but if($formdata[0]['Phase']==3){ to show only the option values from $ahk 3x in dropdown here is my code

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<label for="d13"><?php echo $t[$tmpvalues[0]['Lang']]['d13'];?></label>
<select class="form-control el-text-box" name="d13" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<?php for ($j=0; $j<sizeof($ahk); $j++){ 
$selected="";if($ahk[$j]==$formdata[0]['d13']){$selected="selected";}
?>
<option value="<?php echo $ahk[$j];?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $ahk[$j];?></option>
<?php 
} 
?>
</select>
</div>
```

values of $ahk are

```
$ahk[0]="1X10A";
$ahk[1]="1X20A";
$ahk[2]="1X30A";
$ahk[3]="1X40A";
$ahk[4]="1X50A";
$ahk[5]="1X60A";
$ahk[6]="1X70A";
$ahk[7]="1X80A";
$ahk[8]="3X10A";
$ahk[9]="3X20A";
$ahk[10]="3X30A";
$ahk[11]="3X40A";
$ahk[12]="3X50A";
$ahk[13]="3X60A";
$ahk[14]="3X80A";
$ahk[15]="3X100A";
$ahk[16]="3X160A";
$ahk[17]="3X200A";
$ahk[18]="3X300A";
$ahk[19]="3X400A";
$ahk[20]="3X500A";
$ahk[21]="3X1000A";
$ahk[22]="3X1600A";
$ahk[23]="3X2000A";
$ahk[24]="3X2600A";
$ahk[25]="3X3200A";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `if` statement to check if the array value matches the phase.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<label for="d13"><?php echo $t[$tmpvalues[0]['Lang']]['d13'];?></label>
<select class="form-control el-text-box" name="d13" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<?php
$prefix = $formdata[0]['Phase'] . "X";
foreach ($ahk as $option) {
    if (substr($option, 0, 2) == $prefix) {
        $selected = $option == $formdata[0]['d13'] ? "selected" : "";
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option;?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $option;?></option>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please combine it in my code as i dont know what to delete?

Comment: I've done it, but I think it should be obvious. My `foreach` loop simply replaces your `for` loop.

Comment: i think i something wrong as its not working, maeby i left something behind on the original code, 
                                       <?php } ?>
                                        <?php if($formdata[0]['Meletes_id']>0){ ?>
                                        <!-- <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">-->
                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

Comment: page is not loading

Comment: Check the PHP error log for syntax errors.

Comment: elculator.com - [22/Apr/2021:20:06:12 +0000] "GET /index.php?workflow=update-circuit-form&id=36900&page=db HTTP/1.1" 200 5426 "http://elculator.com/index.php?workflow=update-circuit-form&id=36900&page=db" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36" | - | 0.093 0.219 0.219 MISS 0 NC:000000 UP:SKIP_CACHE_NO_CACHE

Comment: i dont know what else to check

Comment: `200` means there was no error. Do you see anything if you use `View Source`?

Comment: nope i dont have that option, where is that exactly

Comment: In the browser's "View" menu. `View -> Developer -> View Source`

Comment: I mean are you seeing the `<select>` and `<option>` elements there?

Comment: The problem must be somewhere else in the script. If you just put `echo "blah";` before this, do you see it?

Comment: If you don't see something that's echoed before this code, then the problem is earlier in the script and unrelated to this.

Comment: can you modify the code in a different way than the one you did?

Comment: maybe something like this 

<?php for ($j=0; $j<sizeof($surge); $j++){  
                                                    if(strpos($surge[$j],$formdata[0]['Phase'].'Φ')!==false || $j==0){
                                                ?>
                                            
                                                        <option value="<?php echo $j;?>" <?php echo $j == $formdata[0]['d24'] ? "selected" : ""; ?>><?php echo $surge[$j];?></option>
                                                    <?php 
}
}

Comment: I could, but I have to go now and I don't see why my code doesn't work.

Comment: Did you ever check the PHP error log? The message you showed above is the webserver access log.

Comment: [22-Apr-2021 16:22:23 CST6CDT] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')' in /home/customer/www/elculator.com/public_html/pages/update/circuit/form.php on line 1502

Comment: foreach ($ahk as $option) {

Comment: sorry problem is on line 1503
                                              if (substr($option, 0, 2) == $prefix)) {

Comment: There's an extra `)`. If you don't use an IDE to write your code, you should, it will catch things like this automatically. Unfortunately, I don't use mine when answering on SO.